# Trouble understanding WS library in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to learn scala with the play framework and I'm trying to rewrite an old project completely in scala for practice. I have written a route that registers a new subscriber and sends them a thank you email for subscribing, using mandrill. I also have some basic error checking in place. The code is as follows

```
  def create = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
  request.body.validate[Subscriber].map {subscriber =>
    if (!isValidEmail(subscriber.email)){
      Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("message"->"Invalid email address")))
    }
    else{
      collection.insert(subscriber).map {lastError =>
        val data = Json.obj(
          "key" -> Play.current.configuration.getString("mandrill.key").get,
          "template_name" -> "Initial Email",
          "template_content" -> Json.arr(),
          "message" -> Json.obj(
            "subject"-> "Example",
            "from_email"-> "info@example.org",
            "from_name" -> "example",
            "to"-> Json.arr(
              Json.obj(
                "email"-> subscriber.email,
                "name"-> subscriber.fname,
                "type"-> "to"
              )
            )
          )
        )
        WS.url("https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json").post(data)
        Ok(Json.obj("message"->"User created successfully"))
      }
      .recover {
        case e: Throwable => BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> "A user with email ${subscriber.email} already exists"))
      }
    }
  }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> "Not enough parameters"))))
}
```

This works but I want to block the WS call so that I can wait for the response from it before sending back the success message because I would like to return an error if mandrill sends me back an error. So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
  def create = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
  request.body.validate[Subscriber].map {subscriber =>
    if (!isValidEmail(subscriber.email)){
      Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("message"->"Invalid email address")))
    }
    else{
      collection.insert(subscriber).map {lastError =>
        val data = Json.obj(
          "key" -> Play.current.configuration.getString("mandrill.key").get,
          "template_name" -> "Initial Email",
          "template_content" -> Json.arr(),
          "message" -> Json.obj(
            "subject"-> "Example",
            "from_email"-> "info@example.org",
            "from_name" -> "example",
            "to"-> Json.arr(
              Json.obj(
                "email"-> subscriber.email,
                "name"-> subscriber.fname,
                "type"-> "to"
              )
            )
          )
        )
        //This line right below doesn't work
        WS.url("https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json").post(data).map{response =>
            if (response.status == 200){
                Ok(Json.obj("message"->"User created successfully"))
            }
            else {
                BadRequest(Json.obj("message"->"Unknown error"))
            }
        }
      }
      .recover {
        case e: Throwable => BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> "A user with email ${subscriber.email} already exists"))
      }
    }
  }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> "Not enough parameters"))))
}
```

But this comes up with the following error

```
type mismatch;
found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Object]
required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
```

on line

```
 }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> "Not enough parameters"))))
```

can someone explain this to me please. I don't want to use Await. I just want to use map so that I get the results, process them and then send back the "Ok" message. I'm using play 2.3.x and scala 2.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are calling `WS` inside the `map` block of `collection.insert`. That `map` expects that you return a `play.api.mvc.Result`, however `WS.post` with the `map` you have attached to it, returns a `Future[play.api.mvc.Result]`.

Given that the `Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("message"->"Invalid email address")))` returns `Future[play.api.mvc.Result]` and your `collection.insert` returns a `Future[Future[play.api.mvc.Result]]` the common, inferred type is `Future[Object]`

If you change the `map` on `collection.insert` to a `flatMap`, i.e. indicating that instead of `play.api.mvc.Result` you intend to return `Future[play.api.mvc.Result]`, you should get the types to line up, e.g:

```
  def create = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    request.body.validate[Subscriber].map { subscriber =>
      if (!isValidEmail(subscriber.email)){
        Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("message"->"Invalid email address")))
      } else {
        collection.insert(subscriber).flatMap { lastError =>
          val data = Json.obj(
            "key" -> Play.current.configuration.getString("mandrill.key").get,
            "template_name" -> "Initial Email",
            "template_content" -> Json.arr(),
            "message" -> Json.obj(
              "subject"-> "Example",
              "from_email"-> "info@example.org",
              "from_name" -> "example",
              "to"-> Json.arr(
                Json.obj(
                  "email"-> subscriber.email,
                  "name"-> subscriber.fname,
                  "type"-> "to"
                )
              )
            )
          )
          WS.url("https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json")
            .post(data).map{ response =>
              if (response.status == 200) {
                Ok(Json.obj("message"->"User created successfully"))
              } else {
                BadRequest(Json.obj("message"->"Unknown error"))
              }
            }
        }.recover {
          case e: Throwable => BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> "A user with email ${subscriber.email} already exists"))
        }
      }
    }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> "Not enough parameters"))))
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. I wasn't aware of the difference of using flatmap and map and this helped me a lot.